# How do I pass a column name into a select in KDB QSQL?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to wrap a query into a function so I can call it arbitrarily.

I'm struggling to pass in the column name for the `where` clause. In the naked QSQL, I can just do `select from n where premarketGap > 0`, but if I try to wrap it in a function, and pass `premarketGap` as a symbol, it fails.

How do I do it?

Here are my various attempts:

QSQL:

```
mq: {[data;column;center;width] select from data where (column > (center - width)) and (column < (center + width))}
```

Functional SQL attempt:

```
mq:{[data;column;center;width] ?[data;(column > (center - width)),(column < (center + width));();()]}
```

Calling function:

```
mq[n;`premarketGap;0.43;0.05]
```

Naked functional attempt:

```
?[n;(`premarketGap > 0);();()]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `parse` to help form functional qsql queries:

```
parse "select from data where (column > (center - width)) and (column < (center + width))"
?
`data
,,(&;(>;`column;(-;`center;`width));(<;`column;(+;`center;`width)))
0b
()
q)
/ remove the backticks from center, width and column as they are presumed to be columns by parse

?[`data;enlist (and;(>;column;(-;center;width));(<;column;(+;center;width)));0b;()]
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/parse/